# NLog: Capture FaultException<TDetail> in log

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nlog

How do I capture FaultException.Detail object contents using NLog.

Following is my current layout:

```
${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}${onexception:inner=${newline}${exception:format=StackTrace :innerFormat=ShortType, Message, StackTrace  :maxInnerExceptionLevel=10 :separator=${newline}${newline}------ :innerExceptionSeparator=${newline}${newline}*----------*
```

Comment: Think you are waiting for this: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3519 but a more advanced version that can handle generic classes with automatic reflection. Until this happens then you need to supply the Detail-property as parameter to the logging message. Ex: `logger.Error(ex, "Something bad. Detail={0}", ex.Detail)`

Answer (score 0):

NLog 4.7 has been released, and now you can do this:

```
${exception:format=Type,Message,Properties}
```

You can also configure what properties should be included for a specific type of Exception-object:

```
  LogManager.Setup().SetupSerialization(s =>
   s.RegisterObjectTransformation<System.Net.WebException>(ex => new {
      Type = ex.GetType().ToString(),
      Message = ex.Message,
      Status = ex.Status,
   })
  );
```

See also: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Exception-Layout-Renderer

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configure-from-code